# My autoencoder is bad in predicting but seems like a well trained one?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, autoencoder

I developed a basic autoencoder of one layer to predict gene expressions where my input is a set of genes and their expression vector. I started by normalizing the dataset to -1 to 1 values for the expression vector and trained it.

The training loss is pretty good ( > 0.0001) but when i ask it to predict a gene the predicted value is very different from the original value somehow! Which is driving me crazy because i thought the validation loss means exactly the accuracy but clearly this is not the case or i am doing something wrong.

I am using keras for my models and tensorflow as my backend

Here's my code

```python
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, normalize
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Dropout
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
import numpy as np
import csv
from keras.callbacks import CSVLogger
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import optimizers, regularizers

x_train = []
count = 0


f = open('NormlizedGeneExpression.csv', 'r')
reader = csv.reader(f)
for row in reader:
    if count == 0:
#         x=0
        x_train.append(row)
    else:
        x_train.append(row)
    count +=1
    if count == 1002:
        break
f.close()
x_test = np.array(x_train)[0, :5000]
x_train = np.array(x_train)[1:1001, :5000]
encodedRepresentation = []


encoding_dim = 2500
number_of_probes = len(x_train[0])
print(number_of_probes)


print(x_train.shape)


noise_factor = 0.025
x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_train_noise = x_train + noise_factor * np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=x_train.shape)

x_train_noise = np.clip(x_train_noise, -1., 1.)


x_train.shape


x_train.reshape((len(x_train), np.prod(x_train.shape[1:])))


x_train.shape


print(x_train_noise)



with tf.device('/gpu:1'):
    activation1 = 'relu'


    autoencoder = Sequential()
    autoencoder.add(Dense(number_of_probes,input_dim = number_of_probes, activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(10e-5), activation=activation1))
    autoencoder.add(Dense(encoding_dim, activation=activation1))
    autoencoder.add(Dense(number_of_probes, activation='sigmoid'))

    autoencoder.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adadelta(lr=5), loss='mse')

    csv_logger = CSVLogger('epochsOptmizationNormlized.csv', append=True, separator=';')
    autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train, callbacks=[csv_logger], validation_split=0.2, epochs=500,batch_size=4)

predicted = autoencoder.predict(x_train)
meanDiff = (predicted-x_train).mean()

diffMatrix = np.zeros(x_train.shape)
for column in range(len(x_train[0])):
    for row in range(len(x_train)):
        if abs(x_train[row][column]-predicted[row][column])<= 0.001:
            diffMatrix[row][column] = 1
        else:
             diffMatrix[row][column] = 0
print(diffMatrix.mean())
print(meanDiff)
print("number of matches:" + str(sum(sum(diffMatrix))) +" out of: " + 
str(len(diffMatrix)*len(diffMatrix[0])))
```

Running this code for only few epochs gives me a validation loss of 0.0015

```python
 Epoch 8/500
 800/800 [==============================] - 7s 9ms/step - loss: 0.0015 - 
 val_loss: 0.0015
```

Here is a sample of the data:

```python
   array([['0.0036385251687012267', '-0.004624872352987704',
    '-0.0012055354474612501', ..., '0.0', '0.0', '0.0'],
   ['0.0', '0.0', '0.0', ..., '0.0', '0.0', '0.0'],
   ['0.0', '0.009841553016547296', '0.007671589211117045', ...,
    '-0.009578527100737567', '-0.0053043559688294994',
    '0.0012712919264136816'],
   ...,
   ['0.0015377572411164127', '0.003165970790533791',
    '0.004191142284611399', ..., '0.0', '0.0', '0.0'],
   ['0.0', '0.0', '0.0', ..., '0.0', '0.0', '0.0'],
   ['0.0', '0.0', '0.0', ..., '-0.005608291114659858',
    '-0.007025439944708316', '-0.0003316731304368733']], dtype='<U23')
```

The data that I have contains values ranging from 10 to -10. I normalize them and then use that as an input to the encoder as can be shown above in the sample.

Comment: Very hard to identify or reproduce the problem without looking at the data.

Comment: @KonstantinosKokos I added a sample of the data. I hope this helps.

Comment: Your mse loss is quite high w.r.t. to your data. Does it no longer improve if you keep training for the full epochs?

Comment: Why is it high? what do you mean? can you explain more? The best I was able to get was val_loss: 3.8011e-05 and it also keeps improving but slowly.

Comment: @KonstantinosKokos I also tried to get the identity by having the same dimensions for the input, hidden layer and the output. It needed too many iterations to learn that I dont know why! I also disabled any activation but still it needs too many iterations.

Comment: Activations help speed up the learning process, removing them is a bad idea. Maybe use Adam with default parameters rather than Adadelta and see if it changes anything. Also, how did you normalize your data?

Comment: Using normalize form sklearn.preprocessing.normalize @KonstantinosKokos

Comment: This simply turns your non-zero values to unit-norm, meaning that if your initial features are rather sparse (i.e. many zeros), your network can simply learn to always say zero (thus achieving a small MSE) which can trick you into thinking training has converged. Try to instead perform zero-mean, unit-variance normalization, replace Adadelta with Adam and let it train longer, then report on the results.

Comment: @KonstantinosKokos I tried Adam and it is giving me crazy loss! 29457/29457 [==============================] - 7s 241us/step - loss: 598149020.0186 - val_loss: 749529935.8416

Comment: Have you changed anything else?

Comment: @KonstantinosKokos learning rate to 0.3

Comment: Just instantiate adam with the default value `optimizer='adam'`

Comment: @KonstantinosKokos 

Epoch 10000/10000
20498/20498 [==============================] - 5s 248us/step - loss: 0.1634 - val_loss: 0.8743